# Counting Loop Iterations (Python)

Tags: python, loops, object, iteration

I've got a quick question about counting loop iterations in Python. I've created objects that "age" with each iteration and are supposed to "die" at a certain age, but sometimes they live substantially longer. Here's a snippet of my program:

```
def reproduce():
    class Offspring(Species):
        def __init__(self,name,life,attack,move,location,status,species,age):
            area = 1000
            self.name = name
            self.life = life
            self.attack = attack
            self.move = move
            self.location = [random.randint(1,area),random.randint(1,area)]
            self.status = 1
            self.species = 'simple'
            self.age = 1
    for z in [y for y in petri_dish if y.status == 1 and y.life >= 50 and y.species == 'simple']:
        petri_dish.append(Offspring('g' + str(turn/250)+'#'+str(z.name),(random.randint(int(z.life/2),z.life)),(random.randint(int(z.attack/2),z.attack)),(random.randint(int(z.move/2),z.move)),0,1,0,0))
        print 'g' + str(turn/250)+'#'+str(z.name), 'was born.'
def move_around():
    for x in list(petri_dish):
        x.age += 1
        if x.status == 0 or (x.species == 'species' and x.age >= 750) or (x.species == 'predator' and x.age >= 3000):
            print str(x.name) + ' expired. Cells left: ' + str(len(petri_dish))            
            petri_dish.remove(x)
        else:
            x.relocate()
            x.target()
            if len(petri_dish) >= 75:
                for x in list(petri_dish):
                    if x.life < int(turn/25):
                        x.status = 0 
    if turn % 250 == 0:
        reproduce()

while len([y for y in petri_dish if y.status == 1]) > 1:
    turn += 1     
    move_around()
```

The Offspring class is a `simple` species and should die at age 750 or above - ideally at 750 exactly, but that's part of the problem. I haven't figured out how to iterate over my list of objects (the `petri_dish`) and, at any point in the iteration, remove certain objects, whether they're at `status = 0` (dead) or have aged sufficiently.

Sorry if this is a simplistic question, but loops aren't my strong suit... I've been reading up on comprehensions and the like, but any additional material would be appreciated as well. Not to mention an answer to my question! Thanks much.

Comment: is `turn` a global variable? also, can you please reduce your code to something minimal that is necessary to reproduce the problem? currently, you haven't even pointed out the relevant lines in the code.

Comment: I see you are testing for `x.species == 'species' and x.age >= 750`, but it seems to be set to `'simple'` in your class.  It seems this portion of the test will always fail.  Side note: Some of your lines are really long making your code hard to read.  Also, you are creating a class in a function that gets called repeatedly.  Are you sure you don't want that class to live on the top level?

Comment: Thanks Steven! That was a silly mistake on my part. I'll revise my code and try moving the Offspring class to the top level. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may or may not be intended: when you pass a list to list(), a copy of the list is returned (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list). So when you do for x in list(petri_dish), you are getting elements from a copy of your list, NOT your actual list.

The reason I mention this is that the first line of code in your for loop is x.age += 1. This is NOT increasing the age of the items in your petri_dish list. Since you're using age as a determinant for removing items from the list, that seems like a problem.

Comment: No worries; I actually switched my list to a list comprehension. `[y for y in petri_dish if y.status == 1 and ((y.species == 'simple' and y.age < 750) or (y.species == 'predator' and y.age < 3000))]`

Comment: Did that solve the looping issue? Also, I would suggest making some constants for some of the variable values that look to stay the same throughout your program (like the 'simple' or 'predator' species names and 750 and 3000 for death times). Just simple things like simple_death_time = 750, predator_species_name = 'predator'. It will make maintenance much easier as you tinker with things (and will make it easier for others reading your code if you have to post again here asking for help).